# Javascript countdown Timer doesnt work on Safari or IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, svg, safari, jsfiddle

i have a problem. My CountdownTimer wont work on Safari or IE...whats wrong ?
maybe its that common thing, that IE is horrible and wants a other date order.
Maybe somone has a solution...
i dont know what to write...but i have to add some more text to get this posted. http://jsfiddle.net/4jdudnb1/1/

```
var jahr = 2015,
    monat = 2,
    tag = 15,
    stunde = 0,
    minute = 0,
    sekunde = 0;
var zielDatum = new Date(jahr, monat - 1, tag, stunde, minute, sekunde);

function countdown() {
    startDatum = new Date();
    if (startDatum < zielDatum) {
        var jahre = 0,
            monate = 0,
            tage = 0,
            stunden = 0,
            minuten = 0,
            sekunden = 0;
        while (startDatum < zielDatum) {
            jahre++;
            startDatum.setFullYear(startDatum.getFullYear() + 1);
        }
        startDatum.setFullYear(startDatum.getFullYear() - 1);
        jahre--;
        while (startDatum < zielDatum) {
            monate++;
            startDatum.setMonth(startDatum.getMonth() + 1);
        }
        startDatum.setMonth(startDatum.getMonth() - 1);
        monate--;
        while (startDatum.getTime() + (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) < zielDatum) {
            tage++;
            startDatum.setTime(startDatum.getTime() + (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        }
        stunden = Math.floor((zielDatum - startDatum) / (60 * 60 * 1000));
        startDatum.setTime(startDatum.getTime() + stunden * 60 * 60 * 1000);
        minuten = Math.floor((zielDatum - startDatum) / (60 * 1000));
        startDatum.setTime(startDatum.getTime() + minuten * 60 * 1000);
        tage += monate * 30;
        sekunden = Math.floor((zielDatum - startDatum) / 1000);
        if (tage < 10) {
            tage = "00" + tage;
        } else if (tage < 100) {
            tage = "0" + tage;
        }
        document.getElementById("svgdays").innerHTML = tage;
        if (monat < 10) {
            monat = "0" + monat;
        }
        if (stunden < 10) {
            stunden = "0" + stunden;
        }
        if (minuten < 10) {
            minuten = "0" + minuten;
        }
        if (sekunden < 10) {
            sekunden = "0" + sekunden;
        }
        document.getElementById("svghours").innerHTML = stunden;
        document.getElementById("svgminutes").innerHTML = minuten;
        document.getElementById("svgseconds").innerHTML = sekunden;
        setTimeout('countdown()', 200);
    } else {}
}
countdown();
```

Thanks in advance and merry XMas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `setTimeout` get rid of the quotations and brackets in countdown

**This**

```
setTimeout('countdown()', 200);
```

**Should Be**

```
setTimeout(countdown, 200);
```

Also, you cannot access the `innerHTML` of SVG elements, so instead you must use `textContent`:

**This**

```
document.getElementById("svghours").innerHTML = stunden;
```

**Shoud Be**

```
document.getElementById("svghours").textContent = stunden;
```

Check this fiddle in IE, it works
http://jsfiddle.net/4jdudnb1/5/